# Why does not my onClick event work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used this.handleClick in onClick but it alerts a mistake.(this is not difined)

```
var Buttons = React.createClass({
      getInitialState() {
          return {
            field: ':P '
          }
        },
        handleClick(field) {
          return this.setState = {
            field
          }
        },
        render() {
          let count = 1;
          return ( < div >
            < h1 > {
              this.state.field
            } < /h1> {
              buttonValues.map(function(val) {
                return <button key = {
                  count++
                }
                onClick = {
                  Buttons.handleClick
                } > {
                  val
                } < /button>
              })
            } < /div>
          )
        }
    })
    ReactDOM.render( < Buttons / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: you probably need to use `onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `Buttons.handleClick()` directly because `Buttons` is a class. You need to instantiate the class before accessing it's method. And This won't work with React.

So, the best way is to use `this` to access the local methods within the class. And `this.setState()` is a function, to which you need to pass the new state object. Hope it helps!

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
var buttonValues = ['hello','there']
  var Buttons = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
          field: ':P '
        }
      },
      handleClick(field) {
      this.setState({
          field
        })
      },
      render() {
      var _this = this
        return ( < div >
          < h1 > {
            this.state.field
          } < /h1> {
              buttonValues.map(function(val, i) {
                return <button key = {
                  i
                }
                onClick = {() => 
                  _this.handleClick(val)
                } > {
                  val
                } < /button >
        })
  } < /div>
          )
        }
    })
    ReactDOM.render( < Buttons / > , document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
```

Comment: why should I use  `onClick = {() => _this.handleClick(val)}` instead of `onClick = {_this.handleClick(val)}` ?

Comment: `onClick = {_this.handleClick(val)} ` will call the function on the first render itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace

`this.setState = {field}`

by

`this.setState({field: field})`

Answer (score 0):

you are not passing any arguments to your function, also use this.handleClick instead of calling the class.

```
 onClick = {this.handleClick.bind(null, val)}
```

also setState is a function

```
this.setState({field: field})
```